# Vectorization in numpy vs Python map()

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm comparing methods to do calculations against large arrays and wanted to compare the speed of broadcasting operators in numpy versus alternatives. I was surprised to see the speed of the python `map()` function though, and am wondering if someone could explain how this is so much faster than broadcasting.

**Broadcasting**

```
%%timeit farenheit = np.linspace( -10, 20, 1000 )
celcius = (farenheit - 32) * (5/9)
```

4.5 µs ± 99.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

**List comprehension**

```
%%timeit farenheit = np.linspace( -10, 20, 1000 )
[(temp - 32) * (5/9) for temp in farenheit]
```

886 µs ± 4.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**Python 3 `map()`**

```
%%timeit farenheit = np.linspace( -10, 20, 1000 )
celcius = map(lambda temp: (temp - 32) * (5/9), farenheit)
```

248 ns ± 41.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Comment: Why are including `farenheit = np.linspace( -10, 20, 1000 )` part in the timings too? For a better benchmarking (to compare NumPy vs map, etc.), think it's better to pre-process that part.

Comment: The cell magic `%%timeit` should exclude the array creation (whatever is on the first line is ignored). https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Comment: `%%timeit` includes everything in that block. So, `linspace` one is included too.

Comment: @Divakar, I routinely use the cell `%%timeit` to precalculate objects.   For example `%%timeit x = arr.copy() \n x *= 100` lets me time the `*=` without timing the `copy`.

Comment: @hpaulj My point was that the focus is to compare NumPy vs map, etc. and with this Q&A it seems it's the calculation of `celcius` through those different ways. Timing everything, doesn't let us do that. I won't mind seeing the timings of the pre-calculation part separately though.

Comment: A fairer test of the list comprehension would be to start with a list, rather than an array.  e.g. fraenheit.tolist()`.  Iterating on an array is slower than iterating on a list.

Answer (score 3):

`map` is so fast because it's not actually running the calculation. It doesn't return a new list/array with new values, it returns a map object (an iterator) that does the calculation only when the items are needed.

For a fair comparison, you should do `list(celcius)` at the end of your first part. Only then are the calculations executed. If your `lambda` (or another function) had a `print` somewhere in it, you would see that `map()` by itself isn't really executing those commands yet.

To read more on `map`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

An example:

```
def double(x):
    print('hi')
    return x*2

a = [1,2,3]
b = map(double, a)

# notice nothing is printing, the calculation isn't happening as well

c = list(b) # this will print 'hi' 3 times as well as returning the doubled list
```